# Restoring Windows 7 with Ubuntu

Tags: restore

There are many Ubuntu-based operating systems that claim to restore windows. Can Ubuntu do this? I often need to repair my multi-booting computer, or to repairs other computers.

Comment: This question is not clear. Do you mean to restore Windows in computers where just was Windows installed or in dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows installation? What do you mean by "restore Windows?" Do you want to re-install Windows or restore the data files?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using boot-repair. It's explained here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair